# how to evaluate if external display is present

Tags: c, macos, bash, applescript

I need my code to evaluate whether an external display is connected via a mini-display port. I'm thinking I should be able to do this by having a bash command that determines a boolean True/False value for the presence of a file. I'm just not sure what file I should be looking for, presumably something in /dev/

I've also noticed that WindowServer process sends messages to console on connection of the external display such as:

> 21/01/2013 04:24:11.647 WindowServer[81]: Display 0x5b81c5c1:
>   MappedDisplay Unit 1: Startup Mode 1920 x 1080, CGSThirtytwoBitColor,
>   Resolution 1, IOMode 0x3e, IODepth 0x2, IOReturn 0x0

So perhaps another approach would be to have my script monitor the log files for those messages. However, not only am I not exactly sure how to do that without monitoring loads of useless log messages, but it also seems a bit clumsy. There must be a neater way to get the state of the video port, right??

Any suggestions on how to do this (anything in applescript, bash, objective-c, or plain-old c will do)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access information about displays from Image Events.

```
tell application "Image Events"
    launch
    set myDisplays to properties of displays
    quit
end tell
```

[MacScripter](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=28627)

Comment: OK, that's a good start, thx! ) Your line 3 could just as easily be "get properties of every display" - for my knowledge, any reason why you preferred to use 'set' and declare a variable? I followed the link to MacScripter - it looks like I'm going to find a full solution there or through the links to the Developer doc, and it looks like I'm going to need to do it in Obj-C (the one lang' of the 4 I cited that I'm least familiar with), so, development time looks longer than I'd initially hoped...oh well! Thx again for your answer.

Comment: properties of displays = properties of every display. I set a variable so you could call it later from the script you write. Good luck.